# Why : if the matrix $A$ is not invertible, then $L_A$ is not onto.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was reading a book and the following statement was made:

If $A$ is not invertible, then $L_A$ is not onto.

Here, the matrix $A$ is $n \times n$

I'm just curious as to why this is true. Thank you!

Comment: What is $L_A$? The linear transformation associated to $A$? If so, then suppose $L_A$ is onto, prove that it is also injective. Conclude that there is a linear transformation $T$ such that $TL_A = L_AT = L_I$. Now construct a matrix $B$ such that $T = L_B$. Now prove that $AB = BA = I$.

Comment: What is $L_A$? I've not seen that notation.

Comment: $L_A$ is indeed the linear transformation associated to A.

Comment: I changed it to state $A$ is square.

Comment: The "quick answer" to this question depends on what your book has said so far about invertible matrices (or about onto linear transformations, which I assume isn't a lot).

Answer (score 0):

Rank-Nullity Theorem:    $n = \dim (Range(L_A)) + \dim(\ker(L_A)).$  If $A$ is not invertible, then $\dim(\ker(L_A)) > 0,$  and thus $  \dim (Range(L_A)) < n.$  So $L_A$ cannot be onto.